# Unable to decrypt LUKS USB stick on different computer

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, encryption, 18.10, luks

**Background info**

```
Computer one:
OS: Ubuntu 18.04,
Username: userone.

Computer two:
OS: Lubuntu 18.10,
Username: usertwo.
```

---

**The problem**

I am having problems with a LUKS encrypted USB stick.

The USB stick was created on computer one and I have no problems using the USB stick on this computer.  When I take the USB stick to computer two and type in the same passphrase I use on computer one to decrypt the USB stick, computer two gives the following error message:

> Error unlocking /dev/sdd1: Failed to activate device:  Operation not
>   permitted

Any idea why?

Comment: Is `cryptsetup` installed?

Comment: @guillermochamorro Yes already installed: `cryptsetup is already installed at the requested version (2:2.0.4-2ubuntu2)`.

Comment: This is a long shot, but, is your keyboard configuration the same in bot machines? maybe you have a symbol in your pass that is typed differently in both machines. Try writing the password in plain text.

Comment: @guillermochamorro, got it working by chowning the usb drive on the 2nd computer.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

You have to chown the usb stick on the computer you want to decrypt it:

```
sudo chown usertwo:usertwo -R [path to usd stick goes here]
```

After this, it decrypts without a problem.